# xunit - unit test execution isolation?

Tags: unit-testing, xunit.net

Current Error:

> A thread tried to read or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access.

I have no idea which unit test caused this as the error prevents any results from being shown. MSTest just marked the test as failed and moved on. How do i get that behavior in xunit? Are there configurable isolation levels somewhere?

Comment: Try to narrow down (i.e. delete tests) till you get to the problematic one.
Maybe this can help for isolation: http://xunit.github.io/docs/running-tests-in-parallel.html#